# ng.ant.design - How to pass additional parameter to [nzExtra] within [nzCard]

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I am using [nzExtra] to set additional action on my card.

```
<nz-card [nzExtra]="choiceaction" [nzHoverable]="true" *ngFor="let choice of choices; let i = index">
```

I wonder how I can set an additional parameter to the `TemplateRef` like we can use `ngTemplateOutletContext` that is not supported as well. Then I could just use the parameter within the template -

```
<ng-template #choiceaction let-choice="choice">
```

Comment: I don't think It's possible. but can you explain why you need that? You can access every variable that you want to pass as an additional parameter, inside your `ng-template` scope.

Comment: The issue is - within the `ng-template` scope it can only access the first index of the array.

Comment: You can do something like this:

`<nz-card [nzExtra]="choiceaction" [nzHoverable]="true" *ngFor="let choice of choices; let i = index">
     <ng-template #choiceaction>
             {{ choice }}
     </ng-template>
</nz-card>`

Comment: Yeah, I tried the same way. Every time it gets only the first index of the array.

Comment: You can see an example of this here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-wsoqfv It works fine and goes over every index of the array.